# how to use google play game services api in codename one

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

How can i use google play games services api in codename one i want to use it to login in my game and save progress as well to create a leaderboard and achievement.

If it is not possible you may suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the build hint `android.playService.games=true` to include it and possibly other such hints from [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html).

To use it you will need to use [native interfaces](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) as the API isn't bound in Codename One.